# How I Customize UIControlSwich

Tags: ios

I want to customize a UIControlSwitch, but I have a doubt, Can I change the image of the selector of the switch also? I saw many tutorials , and they changes the size, text and Background, but I want make something similar to this( Mundial):

[image: ,]

and additional I want to know if this is a UISwitch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many controls which can do what you're asking. Have a look at CocoaControls, specifically [on this page](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=switch).

I would personally recommend using [this one](https://github.com/samvermette/SVSegmentedControl) (if it has all features you need).